# Variable with multiple entries run in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am running python 2.6.6 and am trying to use a loop to run an snmpwalk against a variable that gets multiple entries in it. This list is populated by a different line of code that is left out and its stored as a variable.

```
import commands
import re
names = switch1 switch2 switch3 
for i in  names:
    count = "snmpbulkwalk -O qv -v 2c -c 2sc4nFB {0} OID-value ".format(names)
    bw = commands.getoutput(count)
    print names+",utilization,"+bw
```

The output I am getting is

```
switch1switch2switch3,utilization,
```

Output expecting

```
switch1,utilization,2345
switch2,utilization,5234
switch3,utilization,45632
```

This will also continually run and I have to break it in order to stop it.

Comment: what are inside `switch1`, `switch2`, `switch3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do as follows, while you didn't iterate the variable and use them properly (your `i` is never used):

```
for name in names:
    count = "snmpbulkwalk -O qv -v 2c -c 2sc4nFB {0} OID-value ".format(name)
    bw = commands.getoutput(count)
    print name+",utilization,"+bw
```

and I think it should be `names = [switch1, switch2, switch3]`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that worked correctly. When I pull in name via a search command it assigns the out put to names and its stored as a str and when I manually enter names it gets stored as a list. The variable considered a list works perfect and the string does not work. How do I make it a str?

Comment: @ReubenGuerrero Can you provide more details? like how do you initialize `switch1` `switch2` `switch3`

Comment: its querying a database and grabbing the switch names from there. Here is the code am using to grab it.

`#!/usr/bin/python

import commands
import re

host = "enm-cli host find --device_role=remote-access-vpn-controller --device_vendor=cisco | grep -v device"
names = commands.getoutput(host)`

Comment: @ReubenGuerrero not very sure what kind of stuff would be put in `names` from your `commands.getoutput()`, but you had your code work already, right?